# Visual Studio Express 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently signed up for a programming class which we need to download Visual Studio Express. 
After downloading I am getting some errors.

> Microsoft Visual Studio connected services package failed
>   Microsoft Azurage Storage connected services package failed

Every time I open up Visual Studio and try to start a new project with visual basic it automatically fails on me and tells me there was a problem and the program restarts.

How can I fix this problem?

Error message I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Apparently, something went wrong during the installation. Perhaps try to uninstall and install again?

Comment: maybe better to install VS2015 Community Edition?